# Key-Value Coding Get Element in List

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-coding

I have two objects:

```
@interface AObject : NSObject

@property NSArray *bObjects;

@end
```

```
@interface BObject : NSObject

@property NSString *name;

@end
```

Using key-value coding on an instance of `AObject`, I can get the list of `bObjects` (`@"self.bObjects"`), and a list of `bObjects`' names (`@"self.bObjects.name"`).

However, what I want is the name of only the first of `bObjects`. My gut is that key-value coding should support list subscripting, like this: `@"bObjects[0].name"`.

But that doesn't seem to exist. How do I get a single entity; the name of an `AObject`'s first `BObject`, using key-value coding?

*Footnote: I realized in my last question I was stupidly conflating NSPredicate and KV-coding.*

Comment: You don't. KVC does not support accessing individual elements within a collection. You should open a radar if you want this support.

Comment: @RobNapier, Can you cheat and use `firstObject` as the key?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. If we assume it would be possible, then you would have troubles (NSOutOfBoundsException) when trying to access an non-excisting object at a given index.

Comment: @Wain: I just tried this. The problem is that `valueForKey:` on an array immediately applies the key to all array elements. So `[aObject valueForKeyPath:@"bObjects.firstObject.name"]` tries to apply `firstObject` to all elements in the `bObjects` array and not to the array itself. - I never found a way to avoid this.

Comment: @MartinR makes sense. It could work with some overriding, but then you could add basically any syntax and result you wanted.

Comment: The only solution for this particular case that I can think of is to add a property "firstBObject" to the `AObject` class. That works, but is not very generic.

Comment: If you want only the name of the first object then you know you want `[self.bObjects objectAtIndex:0]` if it has at least one element. Why do you want to use KVC here?

Comment: @Joe: From a previous (now deleted) question I *guess* that the goal is to take it one step further: Given an array of AObjects, return a new array with the names of the first BObject in each AObject. `valueForKeyPath` would be convenient (if it worked).

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, makes more sense now.

Comment: @MartinR You probably won't believe me but I missed that comment, I only read the one you have with a +1 and then your response to explain the issue otherwise I would not have posted. Feel free to post the answer.

Comment: @Joe: I beg your pardon. Please undelete your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin R mentioned in the comments, currently the best option would be to create a `firstBObject` property in the `AObject` class.

**AObject.h/m**

```
@class BObject;

@interface AObject : NSObject
+ (AObject*)aObjectWithBObjects:(NSArray*)bObjects;
@property NSArray *bObjects;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BObject *firstBObject;
@end

@implementation AObject
+ (AObject*)aObjectWithBObjects:(NSArray*)bObjects
{
    AObject *ao = [[self alloc] init];
    ao.bObjects = bObjects;
    return ao;
}
- (BObject*)firstBObject
{
    return [self.bObjects count] > 0 ? [self.bObjects objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
}
@end
```

**BObject.h/m**

```
@interface BObject : NSObject
+ (BObject*)bObjectWithName:(NSString*)name;
@property NSString *name;
@end

@implementation BObject
+ (BObject*)bObjectWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    BObject *bo = [[self alloc] init];
    bo.name = name;
    return bo;
}
@end
```

**Usage:**

```
NSArray *aobjects = @[
                      [AObject aObjectWithBObjects:@[
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A1B1"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A1B2"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A1B3"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A1B4"]
                       ]],
                      [AObject aObjectWithBObjects:@[
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A2B1"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A2B2"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A2B3"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A2B4"]
                       ]],
                      [AObject aObjectWithBObjects:@[
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A3B1"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A3B2"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A3B3"],
                       [BObject bObjectWithName:@"A3B4"]
                       ]]
                      ];
NSLog(@"%@", [aobjects valueForKeyPath:@"firstBObject.name"]);
```

**Results**

> (
>       A1B1,
>       A2B1,
>       A3B1 
> )

Answer (score 1):

So as it turns out, I had the fortune of being able to simply override `-valueForKey:` in the root class (`AObject`). It bears repeating that `-valueForKeyPath:` calls `-valueForKey:` on every key, which is cool.

Since that might not be applicable to everyone, and this might be too much manipulation of default, expected behavior, this **definitely not** the "right" answer.

But here it is anyway:

```
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string characterAtIndex: [string length] - 1] == ']') // Trying to subscript
    {
        NSRegularExpression *subscriptRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern: @"([a-zA-Z]+)\\[([0-9]+)\\]"
                                                                                   options: (NSRegularExpressionOptions)0
                                                                                     error: nil];

        NSString *key = [subscriptRegex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: string
                                                                 options: (NSMatchingOptions)0
                                                                   range: NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                            withTemplate: @"$1"];
        id valueForKey = [self valueForKey: key];
        if (!key || !valueForKey || ![valueForKey respondsToSelector: @selector(objectAtIndexedSubscript:)])
            return nil;

        NSInteger index = [[subscriptRegex stringByReplacingMatchesInString: string
                                                                    options: (NSMatchingOptions)0
                                                                      range: NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                               withTemplate: @"$2"] integerValue];
        if ((index < 0) || (index >= [valueForKey count]))
            return nil;

        return [valueForKey objectAtIndexedSubscript: index];
    }

    return [super valueForKey: string];
}
```